# OptionButton dropdown appears behind other control nodes

Tags: gdscript, godot-4

I'm getting used to Godot 4.0, and I ran into an issue where the dropdown menu from OptionButton draws behind all the other control nodes (or, at the very least, those further down the scene tree).
[image: An expanded OptionButton list drawn behind other nodes]

[image: Scene tree showing where this OptionButton node is in the tree. The warning icon next to the OptionButton node is informing me about how changing a control node's Z Index does not change its input handling order (which is not an issue here).]

I changed its z-index in the inspector to be higher than the other control nodes, but this didn't help. I've also rearranged the scene tree twice: first, I rearranged it so that everything was in HBox and VBox containers instead of the GridContainer, and that didn't help; and second, to place the HBoxContainer that the OptionButton node is in inside of a CanvasLayer, and this didn't change anything either.

I have suspicions about what's going on (and a really sloppy way of fixing it in mind, involving importing this scene from Godot 3.5 which does work normally). But, I'm wondering if anyone has suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be caused by the `Window` having set `always_on_top` to `true`, making it appear on top of every other window, including the `PopupMenu` from the `OptionButton`.

Thus your first solution is to not use `always_on_top`.

---

If you need `always_on_top`, we could hack it from script by getting the hidden `PopupMenu` and setting its `always_on_top` to match the `Window`:

```
extends OptionButton


func _ready() -> void:
    get_popup().always_on_top = get_window().always_on_top
```

---

Looking further into it took me to this issue: [always_on_top breaks non-embedded popups](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/62382), it seems to be related, although I'm getting the unexpected behavior even with `embed_subwindows` enabled in project settings.